# musicbrainzngs gives partial results when using release_type list

Tags: python, musicbrainz

I have the following code that returns all results ( and all types )

```
import musicbrainzngs
result = musicbrainzngs.browse_release_groups("cc2c9c3c-b7bc-4b8b-84d8-4fbd8779e493")
```

I just want to filter the results in the API vs the code by setting `release_type=[]` list and throw everything else away

```
release_type=['album', 'live', 'single']
result = musicbrainzngs.browse_release_groups("cc2c9c3c-b7bc-4b8b-84d8-4fbd8779e493", release_type=release_type)
```

)

Problem is, this code gives me just the "live & single" releases .. even though I specified `album` as well ...

```
{'release-group-list': [{'first-release-date': '2011-11-25',
                         'id': '36e41dc0-2a0c-4ff7-b043-097534d52bf6',
                         'title': 'Adele Live at the Royal Albert Hall',
                         'type': 'Live'},
                        {'first-release-date': '2011',
                         'id': '37367c39-1c91-4a8c-baa7-0a09c3df4b6b',
                         'title': '2011-02-25: Morning Becomes Eclectic, KCRW-FM, Santa Monica, CA, USA',
                         'type': 'Live'},
                        {'first-release-date': '2012-10-05',
                         'id': '4307ecf9-d0f2-4b95-b7ad-2f8cba84a5e9',
                         'title': 'Skyfall',
                         'type': 'Single'},
                        {'first-release-date': '2011-04-28',
                         'id': 'c9ddd0ed-ba23-4dfc-bb7e-42f8ffb21fb7',
                         'title': '2011-04-08: Paradiso FM, Amsterdam, Netherlands',
                         'type': 'Live'}]}
```

And I do have releases with `type='Album'` without using `release_type` i.e:

```
{
  'first-release-date': '2011-07-13',
  'id': '763f800f-4284-432b-b056-7f6e0aa26bfe',
  'title': 'iTunes Festival: London 2011',
  'type': 'EP'
},
{
  'first-release-date': '2011-07-04',
  'id': '7c2071cb-598d-4a0c-b1d5-a53e2cb9b5f8',
  'title': 'Set Fire to the Rain',
  'type': 'Single'
},
{
  'first-release-date': '2008-01-27',
  'id': '9796da06-2d59-3176-8598-2105f31ee54a',
  'title': '19',
  'type': 'Album'
},
```

## EDIT2

Very strange result when I use `release_type=['album']` ( without `live` & `single` ) - I receive now Album & Live types (?!?!)

```
release_type=['album']
result = musicbrainzngs.browse_release_groups("cc2c9c3c-b7bc-4b8b-84d8-4fbd8779e493", release_type=release_type)

{'release-group-list': [{'first-release-date': '2011-11-25',
                         'id': '36e41dc0-2a0c-4ff7-b043-097534d52bf6',
                         'title': 'Adele Live at the Royal Albert Hall',
                         'type': 'Live'},
                        {'first-release-date': '2011',
                         'id': '37367c39-1c91-4a8c-baa7-0a09c3df4b6b',
                         'title': '2011-02-25: Morning Becomes Eclectic, KCRW-FM, Santa Monica, CA, USA',
                         'type': 'Live'},
                        {'first-release-date': '2008-01-27',
                         'id': '9796da06-2d59-3176-8598-2105f31ee54a',
                         'title': '19',
                         'type': 'Album'},
                        {'first-release-date': '2012',
                         'id': 'ad1343e8-1832-4035-8dcc-0bed2daa5ace',
                         'title': 'Greatest Hits',
                         'type': 'Compilation'},
                        {'first-release-date': '2011-04-28',
                         'id': 'c9ddd0ed-ba23-4dfc-bb7e-42f8ffb21fb7',
                         'title': '2011-04-08: Paradiso FM, Amsterdam, Netherlands',
                         'type': 'Live'},
                        {'first-release-date': '2011-01-19',
                         'id': 'e4174758-d333-4a8e-a31f-dd0edd51518e',
                         'title': '21',
                         'type': 'Album'}]}
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: Which version of musicbrainzngs are you using? There should be "primary-type" and "secondary-type-list" attributes in the result of that call.

Comment: Also, the result you're showing does not include live & single release groups because the Adele artist entry in MB doesn't have release groups of that type. The ones you show are Album+Live, Album+Live, Single+Soundtrack and Album+Live.

Comment: @Wieland mmm the lib says something like 0.2dev

Comment: @Wieland I'm not sure what you mean, so I've edited the question with an example of an album of type=Album.... why I don't receive it when I use it in the release_type=[] ?

Comment: 0.2dev is from march 2012 (or earlier), I really recommend updating the library because (as in this case), the old version does not support primary and secondary release types properly. "Album" is a primary type, "Live" a secondary one. The general "type" key includes the primary type if there are no secondary ones (as is the case for 19 & 21) and a/the secondary one if it exists (all the other ones, whose primary type is still "Album").

Comment: Got it - will do, thanks !